# How to add datetimepicker control in datagridview

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am doing my college project ,i have some problem in my project.

how to add datetimepicker control in datagridview  vb.net,,i try so many option but its not working ..pls tell any solution.

coding for vb.net

Regards,

Prasanth.s

8098077937

Answer (score 0):

```
        Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

            '//Adding DateTimePicker control into DataGridView   
            DataGridView1.Controls.Add(oDTP)

            '// Setting the format (i.e. 02/07/2017 - mm/dd/yyyy)
            oDTP.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short

            '// It returns the retangular area that represents the Display area for a cell  
            Dim oRectangle = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, True)

            '//Setting area for DateTimePicker Control  
            oDTP.Size = New Size(oRectangle.Width, oRectangle.Height)

            '// Setting Location
            oDTP.Location = New Point(oRectangle.X, oRectangle.Y)
            '// Read value from DataGridView into DateTimePicker
            oDTP.Value = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value
            '// Now make it visible  
            oDTP.Visible = True
            '// Force to change date value at oDTP_ValueChanged Event.
            AddHandler oDTP.ValueChanged, AddressOf oDTP_ValueChanged


End Sub

Private Sub oDTP_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = oDTP.Value
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellLeave(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellLeave
    oDTP.Visible = False
End Sub
```